# How to target only the 'names' links using XPath?

Tags: xpath

I have two groups of links: `names` and `addresses` in HTML structured like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <p>names:
    <a href="/navigate/names/a">A</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/navigate/names/b">B</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/navigate/names/c">C</a>&nbsp;
  </p>
  <p>addresses:
    <a href="/navigate/addresses/a">A</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/navigate/addresses/b">B</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/navigate/addresses/c">C</a>&nbsp;
  </p>
</div>
```

How do I target only the `names` links using XPath?

Comment: I don't think xpath will examine the node values for you. However if you put <p myTag="names"> then you can just do an /p[@myTag="names"]

Answer (score 5):

```
/div/p/a[starts-with(@href, '/navigate/names')]
```

or

```
/div/p/a[contains(@href, 'names')]
```

or

```
/div/p[contains(text(),'names:')]/a
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/*/p[starts-with(., 'names:')]/a
```

Comment: +1 It's better to use string value in mixed content data model as XHTML